# How would you write to stdout from a bytecode interpreter?

Tags: c, virtual-machine, stdout, bytecode

I was reading this tutorial on building a simple virtual machine/bytecode interpreter. It had instructions like PUSH, POP, HALT, etc... these instructions are decoded and evaluated in a switch, so you would say if the current instruction equals PUSH, then you would push it to a stack. But what if I wanted to print out a string or character?

In assembly, you would use make a string in `.data`, push the length, then the message, then the file descriptor for stdout (1), the system write call number so 4 (for 32 bit), and then do int 80.

How would I do something like this for a virtual machine? Would I handle it similarly? I thought maybe I could just dump whatever I wanted to write in a register, and then printf the contents when it has something other than (magic number) in it, but that doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: What do you think 'int 80' does?

Comment: @Soren not sure, a system call I think??

Comment: So what do you think happens in that system call?

Comment: it sends the stuff that you push to the system maybe? and the file descriptor is saying write it to stdout? im not too sure.

Comment: I guess it depends on how low-level your "VM" / bytecode interpreter is.  If I were writing one of these as an ordinary C program, running under an OS, I'd define an opcode meaning "putchar", and it would literally pop a word from the stack and call regular old `putchar()` on it, and out the character would come to my screen.

Comment: @SteveSummit Good idea, I'll give that a go, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Printing" is assuming having some kind of IO (input/output) system with an output device capable of presenting data on it (as a printer or display). On a virtual machine such a device can be only virtual as well, and it is up to the VM implementation how it would be emulated. For example it can have a specific well-defined memory range, which is the "video memory", such that writing there is interpreted as sending data to the output device, which can be emulated by, say, a textbox in you VM's interface.

Comment: Hmm, thanks. One question though, are there any typical ways that this is approached? I don't want to "reinvent the wheel".

Comment: Video memory is a very common thing. You have to store the data displayed somewhere, right? Unless it is some kind of serial device, like a teletype, or something, where you just send one character at a time "forgetting" the previous. In this case you can have just a couple of control registers, either memory-mapped as well, or port-mapped (as in the x86, for example).

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look into these.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a way for programs to access the screen - they can't do it "automatically".

For example (as suggested by Eugene Sh.'s comment): create a PUTCHAR opcode, which pops a number from the stack and prints it to the screen (with the normal C function `putchar`).